# How to get a standard color of the neutral button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-resources, android-theme

I am using button with style="`?android:attr/buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle`"

```
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Sign in" />
```

I would like to get its color, so I can use it with other view elements as well.

Currently I am reading its color value like this:

```
int color;

View button = findViewById(R.id.passwordSigninButton);
if ((button != null) && (button instanceof Button))
  color = ((Button) button).getCurrentTextColor();
// -16738680
```

...and it works fine. But I would prefer to get the color associated with the applicable style directly, without need to use of actual button, in case I want to use it without button being in my layout.

So I tried this approach:

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

getApplicationContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(
    android.R.attr.buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle, typedValue, true);

TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
    typedValue.data, new int[]{android.R.attr.textColor});

int color = typedArray.getColor(0, -1);
// -1

typedArray.recycle();
```

But I am getting `-1`, which means I am not getting the color I expected.

How can I get the color from the `android.R.attr.buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle` style?

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion`. I assume that is is at least 21 since you are using `buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle` which was introduced in API 21. Also, are using the support libraries so your buttons are of the type `AppCompatButton` or not?

Comment: @Cheticamp - My `minSdkVersion` is 23. See https://pastebin.com/raw/Xs6LCrka for other details.

Comment: Thanks. Are you using `AppCompatButton` or the non-compat button? I think this matters.

Comment: I see `appcompat-v7:26.1.0` in your pastebin file, so I assume that you are using the `AppCompatButton` but can you confirm this?

Comment: @Cheticamp - The test code contains no button in the layout, so that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Cheticamp - In my other app, where I actually need/want to use this feature, I use `AlertDialog.Builder()` with `setView()` to add a checkbox. The system dialog contains buttons added by `setNeutralButton()` and `setPositiveButton()` methods. Furthermore, I am using `alertDialog.setOnShowListener()` where I want to set the checkbox being same color as the buttons. I hope this clarifies enough my desire. Regardless of type of use, the code for getting a color of the button style `textColor` should be same. I have realized that the proposed code works fine with API 23, but not with API 24+.

Comment: Thanks. I will assume that you are using `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` for the `AlertDialog`.

Comment: @Cheticamp - Yes, I use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`, but as I wrote before, it is irrelevant. If you build a simple app code with no layout, just a code that tries to get a color of the button with desired button style, it will work differently on API 23 and API 24+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*See update for direct derivation below.*

Your approach to determining the color of neutral button text is trying to duplicate the steps that Android takes in determining the color. This processing is under the hood and can change from release to release as I think we are seeing from the responses to this question. I am sure that the Android developers feel free to change the underlying implementation as long as the result is the same, so, even if you can get a solution that works today, it will be fragile and may break tomorrow.

You do have a solution, but it involves creating a layout that you want to avoid. I suggest the following approach which, I believe, will serve your purpose, will be a little more robust and will avoid the need for a layout file. You indicate that you are using `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog` which creates `AppCompatButton` buttons.

The following two lines will give you the color of the neutral button text without a layout or the complication of extracting attributes. I have tested this on an emulator running API 22 and a Samsung S7 running API 24 and both results are consistent with what is seen with an explicit layout.

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton button =
    new android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton(this, null,
    android.R.attr.buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle);
int color = button.getCurrentTextColor();
```

---

**Direct Derivation**

Although I believe that the above solution is the best, the following code will derive the default color of the neutral button for all APIs. This approach simply looks for the `textColor` attribute and, if that is not defined, looks for `textAppearance` and looks at the `textColor` defined there. It looks like the difference between the different APIs is how the color is specified. This solution *may* be robust enough to withstand subsequent updates but *caveat emptor*.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton button =
            new android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton(this, null, android.R.attr.buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle);
        Log.d("MainActivity", String.format("<<<< Button color = 0x%08X", button.getCurrentTextColor()));
        Log.d("MainActivity", String.format("<<<< Derived color = 0x%08X", getNeutralButtonColor(Color.WHITE)));
    }

    private int getNeutralButtonColor(int defaultColor) {
        TypedArray ta;
        int color = defaultColor;
        boolean colorFound = false;
        int textColorResId;
        final int baseAttr = R.attr.buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle;

        // Look for an explicit textColor attribute and use it if it is defined.
        ta = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(null, new int[]{android.R.attr.textColor}, baseAttr, 0);
        textColorResId = ta.getResourceId(0, -1);
        if (textColorResId == -1) { // try to get color if not resource id
            int type = ta.getType(0);
            if (type >= TypedValue.TYPE_FIRST_COLOR_INT && type <= TypedValue.TYPE_LAST_COLOR_INT) {
                color = ta.getColor(0, defaultColor);
                colorFound = true;
            }
        }
        ta.recycle();

        if (textColorResId == -1 && !colorFound) {
            // No color, yet. See if textAppearance is defined.
            ta = obtainStyledAttributes(null, new int[]{android.R.attr.textAppearance},
                                        baseAttr, 0);
            int textAppearanceId = ta.getResourceId(0, -1);
            if (textAppearanceId != -1) {
                // OK, textAppearance is defined. Get the embedded textColor.
                ta.recycle();
                ta = obtainStyledAttributes(textAppearanceId, new int[]{android.R.attr.textColor});
                textColorResId = ta.getResourceId(0, -1);
                if (textColorResId == -1) { // try to get color if not resource id
                    int type = ta.getType(0);
                    if (type >= TypedValue.TYPE_FIRST_COLOR_INT && type <= TypedValue.TYPE_LAST_COLOR_INT) {
                        color = ta.getColor(0, defaultColor);
                        colorFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            ta.recycle();
        }

        if (textColorResId != -1 && !colorFound) {
            ColorStateList colorStateList = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this, textColorResId);
            if (colorStateList != null) {
                color = colorStateList.getDefaultColor();
                colorFound = true; // in case needed later
            }
        }

        return color;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
}
```

Comment: @Ωmega There is a direct way I am sure, but it may involve digging deep into the code to understand what is going on and, as I mentioned, it will be fragile. I think this is the better way because you will be using Android's own internal processing to achieve the desired end and without the added complication of a layout file.

Comment: @Ωmega See update to answer. I can incorporate the API 23 solution if that would help.

Comment: I like it, but **WHY** your API 24+ solution is not working with API 23? A little of digging would be nice to find out a reason. Otherwise, without knowing it, we risk that with next level of API we may face similar/new issue.

Comment: I understand that `textColorResId` is not defined for `android.R.attr.textColor` within `android.R.attr.buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle` in API 23 and lower, but that/why `android.R.attr.textColor` of `textAppearance` is defined only for API 23 and lower makes **no sense** to me.

Comment: @Ωmega So, I already broke the code. I have updated the answer to identify when the color is a specific value rather then a reference and to identify the correct color if the native definition of  `buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle` is overridden in the theme.

Comment: Why you set `colorFound = true;` even when `color = ta.getColor(0, -1);` may return `-1`, so the color is actually not found?

Comment: @Ωmega I have the `colorFound` flag because `color` could take on any value.  `color = ta.getColor(0, -1)` can return -1 for a failure or -1 if the color is opaque white. I make sure that the response will be a color by checking the type, so if `getColor()` returns -1, it is a color and not a failure. You may want to make changes to make this fit without your app. You may want to choose a default color (other than -1) or identify when the routine can't find a color. I will update the routine to explicitly return a default color.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Shouldn't be another `colorFound = true;` after `color = colorStateList.getDefaultColor();` in the last section, so at the end we know if the color was actually assigned or not? I would suggest to add `int defaultColor` as a parameter of `getNeutralButtonColor()` method and at the end check `foundColor` and assign such default color otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the same code that you have given above. I was able to get an Integer value.

**Output: System.out: Printing the color int value: -49023**

```
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.TypedValue;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

        getApplicationContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(
                android.R.attr.buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle, typedValue, true);

        TypedArray typedArray = this.obtainStyledAttributes(
                typedValue.data, new int[]{android.R.attr.textColor});

        int color = typedArray.getColor(0, -1);
        System.out.println("Printing the color int value: " + color);

        typedArray.recycle();
    }
}
```

*Below code has a different style:*

```
 getApplicationContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(
                    android.R.attr.actionButtonStyle, typedValue, true);

 TypedArray typedArray = this.obtainStyledAttributes(
                    typedValue.data, new int[]{android.R.attr.colorForeground});

 int color = typedArray.getColor(0, -1);
 System.out.println("Printing the color int value: " + color);
```

**Output:System.out: Printing the color int value: -16777216**

---

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1
Build #AI-171.4443003, built on November 9, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b08 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.13.3

Comment: I have printed the output I got. I am not sure what could be the issue in your case. Have you tried the same code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create colors.xml inside values folder of the project and define the colors you want to use for the views. eg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="green">#008000</color>
 <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
 <color name="black">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

Then in your styles, refer the colors from this file :

eg :

```
<style name="ButtonColor" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

Then for any other elements you want the color you need not depend on a view and just access from this colors.xml

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

But if you want to really access it from the styles :

```
// The attributes you want retrieved
int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.textColor, android.R.attr.text};

// Parse style
TypedArray typedArray  = obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.stylename, attrs);

// Get color from style
int textColor = typedArray.getColor(0, "default color");

//Check by priting
Log("Retrieved textColor as hex:", Integer.toHexString(textColor));

//recycle
typedArray.recycle()
```